# Faithful action on quotient by center

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, quotient-group, semidirect-product

Suppose $G = A \rtimes B$ is a group, where $B$ acts faithfully on $A.$ Since B acts faithfully on A, $Z(G) \subseteq A.$ If $z \in Z(G),$ then what can we say about the action of $B$ on $\displaystyle \frac{A}{\langle z \rangle}?$ Will it also be faithful?

I can only see that if suppose the action is conjugation, then some $b \in B$ will lie in the kernel of its action on $\displaystyle \frac{A}{\langle z \rangle},$ if and only if $(a,b) \in \langle z \rangle \ \forall \ a \in A.$ I am really stuck in proceeding further. Do we have some general result in this direction?

Comment: Correct $c\in Z(G)$ to $z\in Z(G)$. Also, what is $(a,b)$? Is it a commutator?

Comment: In general no, but the action would be faithful, for example, if $A$ and $B$ were finite of coprime orders.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you very much for your answer. How can we prove it if $(|A|,|B|) = 1?$

Comment: See Theorem 5.3.2 in Gorenstein's book "Finite Groups", for instance.

Answer (score 2):

In general the action of $B$ on $A/\langle z\rangle$ is not faithful. Consider $A=C_4$, $B=C_2$ such that $G\cong D_8$.

Comment: Yes you are right. But when is it true then?

Comment: It really depends on the action. This is no easy "if and only if" theorem. Derek's comment above is only a sufficient criterion.

Comment: @ BrauerSuzuki How can we prove the sufficient criterion, as you said?

Comment: I have already given a reference in the comment under your question, but here is a short argument: let $b\in B$ and $a\in A$. Since $B$ acts trivially on $A/Z$, we have $a^b=az$ for some $z\in Z$. Since $B$ acts trivially on $Z$, $a^{b^2}=(az)^b=a^bz=az^2$. Eventually $a=a^{b^{|B|}}=az^{|B|}$ and $z^{|B|}=1$. Since $|Z|$ and $|B|$ are coprime, it follows that $z=1$ and $a^b=a$.

Comment: thanks. I missed your above reference.

Comment: If $|A|$ and $|B|$ are coprime, then can we say something about the necessary criterion, i.e. B acting faithfully on A implies B acts faithfully on $\frac{A}{z}$?

Comment: This is essentially my argument above. Suppose $b$ acts trivially on $A/Z$, then $a^b=a$ for all $a\in A$, so $b=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.